# How to derive the probability mass function for Zero-inflated Poisson Distribution?

Tags: probability, self-study, poisson-distribution, zero-inflation

I am a maths student and I asked to derive the zero-inflated poisson distributon. I looked it up in the interent and I found the p.m.f. however I have no-idea why it looks the way it looks. Thank you so much for answers.

Comment: Homework? Hint: think of a zeroniflated model as a finite mixture of a point mass at zero (for the excess zeros) and a Poisson distribution. The probability to belong to the point mass is often modelled with a binomial GLM.

Comment: I added the homework tag.  If this is, in fact, NOT homework, my apologies and feel free to remove it.